# Websphere 8.5 session-cookies issue

Tags: session, session-cookies, servlet-filters, websphere-8, jsessionid

To solve cookies related vulnerabilities, I have written wrapper on request and response in one my filter.
In request wrapper I overwrite cookie using following code in getSession method(overridden)

```
HttpSession session = getHttpServletRequest().getSession(false);
String value="JSESSIONID=" + session.getId() +"; Path="+getHttpServletRequest().getContextPath()+"/";
        ((HttpServletResponse)response).setHeader("Set-Cookie",value);
```

In response filter I have overridden addCookie and addHeader methods to do the same.

The above code is working fine for tomcat and jboss, but it is giving issue on websphere 8.5.

For websphere 8.5 it is giving session null in the getSession method `getHttpServletRequest().getSession(false)`

When I inspect network traffic from browsers developer tools then for websphere I observed multiple cookies are getting added on response (one which is we added and other added by server), to avoid this I have done setting in websphere session management to disable the cookies. This solves the multiple cookies problem but null session problem still persists.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What vulnerabilities are you trying to address? You should never manually tamper session cookie created by server container, as it might contain additional SSO/affinity information, and the whole cookie id is not necessary only session id received using `getId()` method. Please remove your filter and create PMR, if you have any security related doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have an explicit "false" parameter in your code, you should pass what your wrapper was passed. You are likely breaking callers who pass true and are therefore not establishing NEW sessions correctly.

You will also likely break session affinity, because you aren't copying the cloneID that follows the session ID.

Why not just set the cookie path in the configuration if that's all you intend to change?